# forwarding (drawing) line in 3d grid

Tags: c, algorithm, graphics, 3d

I need something like Bresenham algorithm but 
not quite and for 3d grid-space.

I got 3d grid of cells (edge size 1.0) need to 
start in point S and advance to point K 'touching' 
all the cells the line touches (even if only edge 
point is touched I need to touch all 8 cells).

Need to use it for traversal writing values to the 
cells or reading values from the cells and need 
it to be as fast as manageable (it would be in massive 
use of drawing millions of such 3d grid lines per frame).

Could somebody say how it could look like?

Comment: nothing comes to my mind, I could use dirty methot of iterating by small step but it would be slow and can skip some cells

Comment: possible duplicate of [Walk a line between two points in a 3D voxel space visiting all cells](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16505905/walk-a-line-between-two-points-in-a-3d-voxel-space-visiting-all-cells)

Comment: youre right that would be on the topic.. tnx.. Though if someone would like to ad yet some soulution feel free to ad it here as those codes mentioned looks strangely complicated, nothing a bit simpler?

Comment: 3D Bresenham isn't exactly a simple algorithm...

Comment: (wanted to upvote your link (as that was usefull too) but undone accidentaly and cannot so upvote here), regz

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider using of Woo and Amanatides grid traversal algorithm: article ["Fast Voxel Traversal Algorithm..."](http://www.cse.yorku.ca/~amana/research/grid.pdf)

Practical implementation is in [grid traversal section here](http://www.flipcode.com/archives/Raytracing_Topics_Techniques-Part_4_Spatial_Subdivisions.shtml)

2d-case illustration:

[image]

Comment: Related answer, uses same paper: https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/81332/63053

Comment: what does the red and blue color mean?

Comment: @Franva Blue for cells having one touch point with line (or edge touching for vertical/horizontal lines), not intersection. Some applications require  counting such cells, others - not