# Get all pixels a ray passses through

Tags: algorithm, graphics, 2d, rasterize

I have a 2 dimensional space and a ray in that space.

[image: grid with ray]

I need to get the coordinates of the red rectangles in the order of the numbers.

My attempt:
I have the starting of the ray which is a double.
I have a value yaw which is the direction in radians.
The I did this to get the coordinate of the next red square.

```
double tanyaw = Math.tan(yaw);
if ((int) (x + 1/tanyaw) == (int) x) {
    x += 1/tanyaw;
    z += Math.signum(tanyaw);
} else {
    x += Math.signum(tanyaw);
    z += tanyaw;
}
```

However:
[image: grid]

That was with yaw = `3*pi/8` note that the line was made in a drawing program and is only approximatly correct.

Comment: Maybe an integer division is done instead of float one? by the way, is this a regular grid for collision optimization?

Comment: @huseyintugrulbuyukisik The ray is like a gunshot and I'm looking for the entity that will be hit first by it, I'm doing this because I quickly can get the entities in those squares so I don't have to check all the entities in the world.

Comment: And you are advancing the ray position / wavefront by small time steps? Maybe like a broad-phase?

Comment: @huseyintugrulbuyukisik I do that to get the chunks of the world, for each chunk I check if any entity in the chunks are hit.

Comment: This looks like a "drawing line on pixels" algortihm but on boxes instead. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_drawing_algorithm

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenham's_line_algorithm

Comment: Look at my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25016603/forwarding-drawing-line-in-3d-grid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Line equation is:

```
x = x0 + t*xd
y = y0 + t*yd
```

For simplicity define that begin of shot leaves at t=0 and the last position to test is at t=1. Then you can simple define step sizes with (assuming that you can simple calculate the end position x1,y1):

```
xstep = 1/(x1 - x0)
ystep = 1/(y1 - y0)
xpos = x0
ypos = y0
```

And then simple loop until you hit the intersection or end using:

```
while(!hitsomething()) {
    if (xpos + xstep - x0 < ypos + ystep - y0) {
           xpos += xstep;
           visit(xpos, ypos);
    } else {
           ypos += ystep;
           visit(xpos, ypos);
    }
}
```