# Finding intersections of lines with grid

Tags: python, algorithm, pandas, numpy, grid

I have trajectory data, where each trajectory consists of a sequence of coordinates and each trajectory is identified by a unique ID.

These trajectories are in **x - y** plane, and I want to divide the whole plane into equal sized cell grid (square grid). This grid is obviously invisible but is used to divide trajectories into sub-trajectories. Whenever a trajectory intersects with a grid line, it becomes a new sub-trajectory with "**new_id**", i.e a trajectory is divided at the intersections of the grid lines, and each of these segments has new unique id.

Finally, I am hoping to pick any random grid cell and retrieve all the sub-trajectories in that cell.

Please suggest me a way to divide the 2d plane into the grid, and how should the trajectories be segmented on encountering grid lines. I am working on Python, and seek some python implementation links, suggestions, algorithms, or even a pseudocode for the same.

Please let me know if anything is unclear.

Answer (score 1):

Grid indexing is simple:

```
x_idx =  Floor(x / CellSize)  //rounding it integer down
```

But finding intersections with grid depends on way - how trajectories are defined. If they are polylines - sequences of straight segments - just calculate intersections of line segments with grid lines

```
 X = k * CellSize
 Y = l * CellSize
```

in k,l intervals between starting and ending cells of segment

Example: polyline starts in point x[0], y[0]. This corresponds to cell with indexes

```
x_idx[0] =  Floor(x[0] / CellSize)
y_idx[0] =  Floor(y[0] / CellSize)
```

The find cell for the end of the first segment `x[1], y[1]`. If cell indexes remain the same, entire segment lies in a single cell and has no intersection with grid. If `x_idx[1]` is larger than `x_idx[0]`, then segment intersects vertical grid lines

```
(x_idx[0] + 1) * CellSize   //right border of the initial cell
(x_idx[0] + 2) * CellSize   
...
(x_idx[1]) * CellSize       //left border of the final cell
```

[How to find intersection point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45052309)

P.S. If segments are long and usually intersect many cells, it is worth to use advanced algorithms for intersection calculation like [Amanatides and Woo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25016603/forwarding-drawing-line-in-3d-grid/25017020#25017020)

Comment: Please can you explain the finding intersection part in more detail. Each trajectory consists of number of x,y points,  so yes they are sequence of segments. I am unable to catch the terms "k" and "l" u mentioned in the suggestion, also **y_idx** will be the same as x_idx ?