# How can you iterate linearly through a 3D grid?

Tags: algorithm, math, optimization, graphics

Assume we have a 3D grid that spans some 3D space. This grid is made out of cubes, the cubes need not have integer length, they can have any possible floating point length.

Our goal is, given a point and a direction, to check linearly each cube in our path once and exactly once.

So if this was just a regular 3D array and the direction is say in the X direction, starting at position (1,2,0) the algorithm would be:

```
for(i in number of cubes)
{
     grid[1+i][2][0]
}
```

But of course the origin and the direction are arbitrary and floating point numbers, so it's not as easy as iterating through only one dimension of a 3D array. And the fact the side lengths of the cubes are also arbitrary floats makes it slightly harder as well.

Comment: are all the cubes in the grid the same size? if yes just multiply your coordinates `p` by the floating size of cube like `p' = (p-grid_origin)*cube_size` and you got integer index `p'` as result but be careful about rounding rule to match your needs ... If not may be sharing image would be a good idea to see what you dealing with ...

Comment: I am dealing with a 3D texture for voxel ray tracing. It's not something I can easily show :p. I cand show the final image but not the texture itself.

Comment: in such case see my [GLSL volumetric 3D back raytracet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48092685/2521214) but the multiplication should work ... What you need to do is DDA through your grid

Comment: what is DDA? Also that formula you just gave is not fully correct, point P need not be aligned with the grid so in that case p' is not guaranteed to eb an integer

Comment: It is correct once you substract the grid origin (center of your `[0][0][0])` cube) that aligns it. [DDA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_differential_analyzer_(graphics_algorithm)) is standard algorithm to rasterize a line it can be easily used in any dimensionality and is even faster than Bresenham for more than a decade now due to architecture changes in computers. see related [Precise subpixel line drawing algorithm (rasterization algorithm)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24682318/2521214)

Comment: Anyway you should get familiar with [Wolf and Doom ray casting techniques](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47251071/2521214) just port it to 3D like I did in the first link I gave you

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25016603/forwarding-drawing-line-in-3d-grid/25017020#25017020

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume that your cube side lengths are `s = (sx, sy, sz)`, your ray direction is `d = (dx, dy, dz)`, and your starting point is `p = (px, py, pz)`. Then, the ray that you want to traverse is `r(t) = p + t * d`, where `t` is an arbitrary positive number.

Let's focus on a single dimension. If you are currently at the lower boundary of a cube, then the step length `dt` that you need to make on your ray in order to get to the upper boundary of the cube is: `dt = s / d`. And we can calculate this step length for each of the three dimensions, i.e. `dt` is also a 3D vector.

Now, the idea is as follows: Find the cell where the ray's starting point lies in and find the parameter values `t` where the first intersection with the grid occurs per dimension. Then, you can incrementally find the parameter values where you switch from one cube to the next for each dimension. Sort the changes by the respective `t` value and just iterate.

Some more details:

```
cell = floor(p - gridLowerBound) / s   <-- the / is component-wise division
```

I will only cover the case where the direction is positive. There are some minor changes if you go in the negative direction but I am sure that you can do these.

Find the first intersections per dimension (`nextIntersection` is a 3D vector):

```
nextIntersection = ((cell + (1, 1, 1)) * s - p) / d
```

And calculate the step length:

```
dt = s / d
```

Now, just iterate:

```
if(nextIntersection.x < nextIntersection.y && nextIntersection.x < nextIntersection.z)
    cell.x++
    nextIntersection.x += dt.x
else if(nextIntersection.y < nextIntersection.z)
    cell.y++
    nextIntersection.y += dt.y
else
    cell.z++
    nextIntersection.z += dt.z
end if
if cell is outside of grid
    terminate
```

I have omitted the case where two or three cells are changed at the same time. The above code will only change one at a time. If you need this, feel free to adapt the code accordingly.

Comment: I am a bit confused.

What is "gridlowerbound"

And you do the operation /d twice once with a vector once with a scalar. What is this notation supposed to denote?

Comment: `gridLowerBound` is the lower corner of the grid (where it starts). `/d` is component-wise division. If scalars are involved, it is simple division.

Answer (score 1):

Well if you are working with floats, you can make the equation for the line in direction specifiedd. Which is parameterized by t. Because in between any two floats there is a finite number of points, you can simply check each of these points which cube they are in easily cause you have point (x,y,z) whose components should be in, a respective interval defining a cube.

The issue gets a little bit harder if you consider intervals that are, dense.

The key here is even with floats this is a discrete problem of searching. The fact that the equation of a line between any two points is a discrete set of points means you merely need to check them all to the cube intervals. What's better is there is a symmetry (a line) allowing you to enumerate each point easily with arithmetic expression, one after another for checking.

Also perhaps consider integer case first as it is same but slightly simpler in determining the discrete points as it is a line in Z_2^8?

Comment: Also I don't know if this is more efficient as there are typically more line points than grids in total, if low grid resolution, then simply check each grid if contains line.