# Get cell Id of mesh which are instersected with line

Tags: geometry, coordinates, computational-geometry

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dzSp7.png)

I have such condition and I want to get those cell Ids which are intersected with line so is there any relation to compute this condition fast and efficiently. Cells may be cuboid, tetrahedrons etc.

Comment: Too wide and vague question. [Look at this for rectangular grid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25016603/)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.